# Resharper: display expression value during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, resharper, coderush

Quick question about Resharper.

It is possible to display expression value during debugging like in CodeRush?

[image]

Or is there any other CodeRush alternative that can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen that feature in ReSharper, however, since you asked for an alternative that can do that, I know [OzCode](http://oz-code.com/) does it:

[image]